# Slow query what is wrong?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
explain select full_name country_name, cc.country_code_id country_id, 
r.name region_name, r.region_id, wc.accentcity city_name, wc.city_id,
lower(concat_ws(' ', wc.city, r.name, cc.full_name)) as search1,
lower(concat_ws(' ', wc.city, cc.full_name)) as search2
from worldcities wc
inner join regions r on wc.region = r.region_id
inner join country_codes cc on wc.country = cc.country_code_id
-- where city like 'paris%' and full_name like 'fr%'
having 
search1 like 'paris f%' or 
search2 like 'paris f%';
```

Which outputs this:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------+----------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys  | key            | key_len | ref                         | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------+----------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cc    | index  | PRIMARY        | full_name      | 144     | NULL                        |  315 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | wc    | ref    | country_region | country_region | 4       | vpromote.cc.country_code_id | 2544 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | r     | eq_ref | PRIMARY        | PRIMARY        | 4       | vpromote.wc.region          |    1 |             |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------+----------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+-------------+
```

Here are the indexes on worldcities

```
+-------------+------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table       | Non_unique | Key_name       | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------------+------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| worldcities |          0 | PRIMARY        |            1 | city_id     | A         |     3170651 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| worldcities |          1 | city           |            1 | city        | A         |     3170651 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| worldcities |          1 | country_region |            1 | country     | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| worldcities |          1 | country_region |            2 | region      | A         |        1254 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------------+------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

here are the tables:

```
mysql> explain worldcities;
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| city_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| country    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| region     | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| city       | varchar(65)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| accentcity | varchar(65)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> explain regions;
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| region_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| country   | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| region    | char(2)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name      | varchar(115)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> explain country_codes;
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| country_code_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| full_name       | char(48)         | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| short_code      | char(3)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| listing_order   | int(11)          | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I can not figure out what to do to speed this up, this query takes about 9 seconds to run.
I have another query that takes less than 1 second, but it doesn't return results and looks like this:

```
select full_name country_name, cc.country_code_id country_id, 
r.name region_name, r.region_id, wc.accentcity city_name, wc.city_id
from worldcities wc
inner join regions r on wc.region = r.region_id
inner join country_codes cc on wc.country = cc.country_code_id and r.country = cc.country_code_id
where full_name like 'fr%'
```

So, what can I do to speed the first one up?

Comment: Turn the select into a view so that ``search1`` and ``search2`` are view columns and then add an index for each one.

Comment: There's no concept of adding an index to a view in MySQL.

Comment: all of your indexing and optimization are not going to make a bit of difference with wildcard searches....you have to scan the entire table when you say things like `search1 like 'paris f%`  I suggest that you redesign your schema so that either 1) you avoid wildcards 2) if you must do wildcard searches you are scanning the smallest amount of data possible with as few joins as possible.

Comment: @mrkb80 with the wild card at the end of the search an index can be used. If the wildcard is at the beginning an index can't be used.

Comment: thanks for the correction. I still submit that wildcard searches should be avoided at all cost either through better ETL or database design.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do:

```
select full_name country_name, cc.country_code_id country_id, 
r.name region_name, r.region_id, wc.accentcity city_name, wc.city_id,
lower(concat_ws(' ', wc.city, r.name, cc.full_name)) as search1,
lower(concat_ws(' ', wc.city, cc.full_name)) as search2
from (select accentcity city_name, city_id, city from worldcities where city='paris') as wc
inner join regions r on wc.region = r.region_id
inner join country_codes cc on wc.country = cc.country_code_id
-- where city like 'paris%' and full_name like 'fr%'
;
```

(or `where city like 'paris%'` depending on what the city name can be)